# In Azure DevOps, I'm trying to create a pipeline in order to create a test plan and upload the test case stored in csv file to the test plan

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-automation

How to automate the creation and upload of test cases to test plans using Azure DevOps pipelines

Steps:

1. create a pipeline
2. store excel sheet containing test case
3. create a test plan
4. upload test case from excel sheet to test plan

Comment: What have you tried on your own so far? What research have you done?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, importing CSV to test plan is just available in Azure DevOps UI , currently, there is no built-in Task or REST API to do that.

If you want to request this feature, you could post it here - https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?entry=suggestion&space=21&preview2=true